# Proper SE site to ask about Science phrase equal to religion phrase

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I like to ask this question but do not know what Stack Exchange site is the proper site to do so.

#### Title

> I like to know what is the equal term of religion sin phrase in science.

#### body

> I thought it could be abnormally, but i also thought it could not be
>   correct because it could not fit correctly when the time series of
>   actions by current abnormally could be normal in culture.
>
> So at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin) it said :
>
> > In a religious context, sin is an act of transgression against divine
> >     law. Each culture has its own interpretation of what it means to
> >     commit a sin.
> >      
> >     Divine law is any law that is understood as deriving from
> >     a transcendent source, such as the will of God or gods, in contrast
> >     to man-made law. Divine laws are typically regarded as superior to
> >     man-made laws, sometimes due to an understanding that their source has
> >     resources beyond human knowledge and human reason. They are accorded
> >     greater authority, and cannot be changed by human authorities.
>
> So based of this diving law definition, does exist sin at science?

Which site would take this question?

Comment: I’ll save you the trouble: Science doesn’t deal in metaphysical, moral, ethical, normative, or subjective realms. There is no analog to sin in science (there is the concept of scientific integrity, eg not engaging in fraud, but that’s a societal concept *about* science, not a subject of science itself). As Dawkins put it: science and religion are “Non-overlapping magisteria”.

Comment: @DanBron That's how Gould put it. Dawkins rejects Gould's phrase as religeous apologetics; Dawkins says, notions particular to religion are absurd & religion has no domain. Wikipedia: "Richard Dawkins has criticized Gould's position on the grounds that religion is not divorced from scientific matters or the material world. He writes, "it is completely unrealistic to claim, as Gould and many others do, that religion keeps itself away from science's turf, restricting itself to morals and values." (Not that Dawkins thinks religion has authority in morals & values anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the equivalent to "divine law" might be "natural law", whatever that means. That sounds like it might be Philosophy, if anything.